Bilingual Chinese-English poetry books
I am looking for anthologies of Chinese poetry, with the following properties:

bilingual, i.e. includes both original (simplified) Chinese and English translation;
broadly covers classical poetry, as opposed to specific authors or periods.


The site Goodreads has many. Here is one: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/681956.The_Heart_of_Chinese_Poetry

Thank you, but after searching, I could not find "many" as you say. The one book you mention is quite what I'm looking for except that the Chinese text is in traditional characters. Would you mind sharing the keywords you used in your search?

Sure: bilingual Chinese poetry books But the one I showed you above was one of about five on that same site. The site has a search box half down the page. :)

The anthology Chinese Poetry, edited by Wai-Lim Yip and published by Duke University Press meets at least 1.5 of your qualifications: it is a broad, classical anthology. It certainly has both Chinese and English writing: the translations include both a spare, character-by-word run-through and a full translation, in addition to many scholarly notes. I don't read Chinese characters, so I can't tell whether they are simplified or traditional; I suspect the latter.
It's at least good enough to have merited a second edition, and is not too expensive, which is always nice.

Thank you, upvoted. Indeed, and unfortunately for me, the Chinese text is in traditional characters (and, strangely, in a handwriting-style font). Still, a useful reference to know.

Have you tried searching in Chinese? Using this search term: 中国古典诗词英译本
I end up with some such as this one (machine translation):

Selected English Translations of Chinese Classic Poems
(Chinese-English) author Yin Shaodong
Category: Publishing / Non-fiction
Press: Chinese University Press / 2019-09
Provided by: Chinese University of China Press



Brief introduction of the work
This book is a selection of 70 classic
Chinese poems, lyrics, small orders and inscriptions, most of which
are familiar to Chinese and can be recited. Classical Chinese poetry,
like stars, is the most splendid part of traditional Chinese culture.
These poems, whether romantic, realistic, aesthetic, or sentimental,
all embody the poet's feelings and the mark of the times, and conceal
the Chinese nation's view of nature, ethics, values, and world view.
The construction of cultural soft power is an important task of
China's foreign cultural exchanges, and it is the bounden duty of the
foreign language community to better disseminate Chinese classical
poetry to foreign countries and help foreign readers better understand
Chinese culture. Over the past 100 years, many scholars have made
great efforts in this area. This book is an attempt by the translator
in addition to teaching English, and the root of this attempt mainly
comes from the translator's love for ancient Chinese poetry, hoping to
share the beauty of ancient Chinese poetry through English.

Searching in simplified characters tends to filter out the traditional character books.

Excellent suggestion. I had not tried that. Thank you.
